# JSON hide "null" data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file and I am displaying in a bootstrap table.

Here is the code that I am using to display:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        content = '<h1><p class="p1"><span class="s1">' + 
                  data.test.name + '</span></p></h1><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>Section:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.section + '</td></tr><tr><td>Synonyms:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.synonyms + '</td></tr><tr><td>Container:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.container + '</td></tr><tr><td>Reference Ranges:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.reference + '</td></tr><tr><td>Availability:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.availability + '</td></tr><tr><td>Special Handling:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.specialHandling + '</td></tr><tr><td>Additional Comments:</td><td>' + 
                  data.test.additionalComments + '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
            $(content).appendTo("#main");
            $("#main").fadeIn( );

    });
});
```

I am wanting to hide any value that is = to "null" and having a hard time.

Comment: That isn't php...it's JavaScript.

Comment: this is actually javascript

Comment: a) That isn't PHP b) You'll have to strip that down to the bare minimum of necessary markup; there's no way anyone is going to pore through all that code on a single line.

Comment: loop through the values. If it's not null add it to the string. If it is null, don't add it to the string.

Comment: What do you want for an end result?  Empty `<td>` elements?  `colspan`?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried:  `function data(value){
    if(value === null){
        value = '';
    }
    return value;
}` and yes just empty or nonbreaking spaces would be great.

Comment: you could do it server-side, replacing null data with empty string before returning since null doesn't really serve a purpose in javascript.

Comment: Are you actually getting a string with a value of "null" back? Or just a missing and/or empty element? (a sample of the actual data would help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want empty values and have no possible falsey values returned this will work for both null and missing values:

**Adapted to work in a fiddle**

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keJ68/)

```
var data = {
    test: {
        name: "bob",
        section: null,
        synonyms: "this, that",
        container: "box",
        reference: null,
        availability: null,
        specialHandling: "be careful",
        additionalComments: "No comment"
    }
};

var content = '<h1><p class="p1"><span class="s1">' + 
          (data.test.name || '') + '</span></p></h1><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>Section:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.section || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Synonyms:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.synonyms || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Container:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.container || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Reference Ranges:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.reference || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Availability:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.availability || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Special Handling:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.specialHandling || '') + '</td></tr><tr><td>Additional Comments:</td><td>' + 
          (data.test.additionalComments || '') + '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    $(content).appendTo("#main");
    $("#main").fadeIn( );
```

**Version 2**

This version uses a scrub function to remove other values such as "()".  If more conditions are added, then it would probably be a good idea to revisit the scrub logic...

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keJ68/1/)

```
// Sample dataset
var data = {
    test: { 
        "name": "RNA Polymerase III Antibody", 
        "id": 96800, 
        "container": null, 
        "reference": null,
        "section": null, 
        "synonyms": "()", 
        "availability": null, 
        "specialHandling": null, 
        "additionalComments": null 
    }
};

// Extra assignment kept for clarity
function scrub(inStr) {
    inStr = inStr || '';  // Set to self if it is a truthy value
    inStr = "()" === inStr ? '' : inStr;
    return inStr;
}

var content = '<h1><p class="p1"><span class="s1">' + 
          scrub(data.test.name) + '</span></p></h1><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>Section:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.section) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Synonyms:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.synonyms) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Container:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.container) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Reference Ranges:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.reference) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Availability:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.availability) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Special Handling:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.specialHandling) + '</td></tr><tr><td>Additional Comments:</td><td>' + 
          scrub(data.test.additionalComments) + '</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    $(content).appendTo("#main");
    $("#main").fadeIn( );
```

Comment: One more question almost the exact same code on another page and this one returns JSON with result of  "()" meaning empty and I want to hide if = "()" on that page would this also work in that case? Sample json `{
    "tests": [
        {
            "name": "RNA Polymerase III Antibody",
            "id": 96800,
            "container": null,
            "reference": null,
            "section": null,
            "synonyms": "()",
            "availability": null,
            "specialHandling": null,
            "additionalComments": null
        },
    ]
}`

Comment: no, any string will evaluate to true.  The logic above just says use the first value if it evaluates to true, otherwise use the second value. I'll add this in.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment already mentioned you did not say how you would like to output the values
Here is something that should get you going:

Assume we have this data returned

```
var data = {};
data.test = {
    section: "mySection",
    synonyms: "mySyn",
    container: "myContainer",
    reference: undefined,
    availability: "myAvail",
    specialHandling : undefined,
    additionalComments: "myComment"
}
```

And you have an object with the same keys as your data.test

```
var labels = {};
labels.test = {
    section: "Section",
    synonyms: "Synonyms",
    container: "Container",
    reference: "Reference Ranges",
    availability: "Availability",
    specialHandling: "Special Handling" ,
    additionalComments: "Additional Comments"
}
```

The following function could write the data

```
function writeTablerow(labels, data){   
    for (var key in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] !== undefined) {
          console.log(labels[key], data[key]);
       }
    }
};
```

You would call it like this:

```
writeTablerow(labels.test, data.test);
```